# Find more than 1 name with laravel relationships

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

I have 2 models: "benefactor" and "abilities".

The benefactor table has a column named "abilities_id" and it has more than one value, like "AB2,AB3".

In the abilities table these ids have names. For example: "AB2 = Money Resource", and "AB3 = Language Skills"

How can I get the names of abilities with relationships in Laravel?

Comment: Could you provide an example of the tables and data? Your question is a bit confusing. Also, what have you tried?

Comment: You can use the method that is used in the scenario that post having many tags. This is method is achieved using many to many relationship. 
You can have to create three tables for that,.. 1. benefactors , 2.abilities and 3.benefactor_abilities (attributes => benefactor_id, ability_id referencing both tables using foreign keys).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Your Data Structure Like This :

`benefactor` Table -

`benefactor_id | abilities_id`
: `1 | AB2` , `2 | AB3`

`abilities` Table -

`abilities_id | names`
: `AB2 | Money Resource` , `AB3 | Language Skills`

Using Query Builder Solution Would Be :

```
$names = DB::table('abilities as a')
         ->join('benefactor as b', 'b.abilities_id', '=', 'a.abilities_id')
         ->get(['a.names']);
```

Change the field names according to your needs.